# How to automatically inherit permissions of a directory to all sub-directories/files which are created later?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, command-line

I've a directory say `qa` at `/home/tom/qa/` and I've applied all permissions i.e. read, write, execute to `qa` directory ex - `chmod -R 777 /home/tom/qa/`

Now some script/command runs and dynamically creates some directories/files inside `qa` with suppose `n` level.

For all newly created directories and files, I want same permissions as of `qa` directory i.e. 777 to be applied automatically i.e. without again issuing `chmod` command.

Please guide to achieve this.

I referred [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/465381/grant-permission-for-new-created-files-inside-folder-automatically) and but that requires additional package to be installed and we're restricted to do that.

Comment: You will need to set umasks accordingly

Comment: @RamanSailopal, I'm not much into LInux. Can you please give more details about what mentioned like commands, references etc.

Comment: cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html

Comment: @RamanSailopal : `umask` does not really help here, becuase directories outside the referred directory tree should keep their own permissions.

Comment: @Alpha : I don't think there is a way to achieve this. You say _some script/command runs_ .... You don't even know **who** is running that script, and the Linux file system does not offer the possibility to control file permissions in this way. The only possibility I see is that **you** provide the script which is going to be executed, so you can build the required logic into it.